# PostGIS on Fedora27

Tags: postgresql, fedora, postgis

I'm trying to get PostGIS installed on Fedora27 and Postgres 9.6.  When doing this on Windows, I can just use the Stack Builder, but that doesn't appear to be a utility available on the Fedora distribution.  I have tried using `dnf` to install, but it's not able to find the repo, and a direct download of the RPM that is tested for Fedora27 is failing to install properly (hanging at 98% and then cancelling).

Can you point me to how to get up and running?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`dnf install postgis` (and possibly `postgis-utils`) should do it.

If it's not, something else is going on. Are you able to install other software? What repo was it unable to find, and what exact error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

The PostGIS library isn't added to the repositories that dnf checks as of now, so

`sudo yum install postgis`

adds the extensions.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. DNF is a drop-in replacement for Yum, and uses the same repo configuration files. If Yum is working and DNF is not, something else is wrong.